# MySQL > How to count items per brand then display "brand name" and "number of items" in rows / two separate columns?

Tags: mysql

I am very new in MySQL so I guess my issue will be quite easy to fix for MySQL specialists.
I am building a Wordpress site with Crocoblock JetEngine to reference used vehicles.

Here is how the table is structured : [screenshot : wp_686591_postmeta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5AfW.png)

I need to create SQL queries to display statistics. I am facing an issue.

I was able to build the below query to count the number of vehicles per brand :

SELECT COUNT(meta_key) as 'nombre de véhicules' FROM `wp_686591_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'marque'
GROUP BY meta_value;

The query returns the number of vehicles per brand as you can see on the screenshot [screenshot : number-of-vehicles-per-brand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq7E1.png) but brands are not displayed. I've tried many combinations, watched tutorials but none of the queries work the way I want.

How may I add the brands so each row displays the brand name in the first column and the total number of vehicles in the second column ?

French > English :

nombre de véhicules = number of vehicles;

marque = brand

Many thanks for any help on this !

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the meta_value in order to visualize it

```
SELECT meta_value as 'marque', COUNT(meta_key) as 'nombre de véhicules' FROM wp_686591_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'marque' GROUP BY meta_value
```

Comment: Logic ! it works well, Thanks a lot for your prompt reply !

Comment: I will appreciate if you accept my answer as the best one. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Is there anything special I must do ?

Comment: On the left of my anwser you can accept it.

Comment: Ok. I clicked on "this answer is useful".